# CSS button:active sometimes makes the button to not function

Tags: html, css, button

Whenever I'm using this in CSS (which is important to me) :

```
.button:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Buttons don't want to function on particular areas depending where you click on them. (positions do happen but jQuery doesn't start)
Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/3/)

You'll see that sometimes they don't react depending if you hit the right spot. Its a little bit harder to notice because it happens. For example, try hitting the contact button just a little bit bellow the letter A. Or hit the About button just below the O letter.

When I delete the :active function buttons work normally. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you experiencing this in one browser or all browsers? If one, which one?

Comment: @SeanKeating Check the live demo, I have tested it with Chrome and IE. I believe it does happen in all browsers.

Comment: To add clarification - buttons do not react when clicking at top of buttons. You can declare top:10px to make it more clear. As I can understand it can be reproduced in any browser.

Comment: @SergiyT. It doesn't only happen at the top. Happens in random spots.

Comment: @SeanKeating Edit, it seems to be happening only in Chrome, but I have noticed another problem in IE now, great.

Comment: Yup... works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @Dynamic Thanks for the info, now tell me how to fix it! :)

Comment: I'm trying to fix it myself :). I promise you I'll answer the question when I got it :P

Comment: @Dynamic Oh, if only you would know how much am I looking forward to that! ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the height on all the buttons to 100% and it eliminated the problem on my browser.  I am using Chrome.  Here is what i did.

```
#btnhome {
margin-left: 121px;
width: 84px;
**height: 100%;**
background-color: black;
border: none;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMF5r/38/) Its not working for me on Chrome like this. I've only changed the height to 100% on all buttons.